# sql: count of all values in all columns and convert them into rows

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have a table that includes multiple columns (more than 200 cols) and all values in all cols are either 0 or 1, like the following:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |

What I want to do is to count all of the zero and one values for each columns and display them row-wise like the following:

| columns | one_values | zero_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col1 | 1 | 2 |
| col2 | 2 | 1 |
| col2 | 3 | 0 |

I am trying to write my query like the following:

```
select 'col1', 
       sum(case when col1=1 then 1 else 0 end) one_values, 
       sum(case when col1=0 then 1 else 0 end) zero_values
from t
union all
select 'col2', 
       sum(case when col2=1 then 1 else 0 end) one_values, 
       sum(case when col2=0 then 1 else 0 end) zero_values
from t
```

however, since I have too many columns, I would get the resource exceed error. I was wondering if anyone can suggest a more efficient way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] as column, 
  countif(1 = safe_cast(split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] as int64)) as one_values,
  countif(0 = safe_cast(split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] as int64)) as zero_values
from your_table t, unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv
group by column
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much! just a general wondering, what if there are null values and I also want to count them and record the sum of nulls as a column like the other two? @mikhail

Comment: just simply add `countif(safe_cast(split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] as int64) is null) as null_values` to select statement